# Undefined argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript

Am new to TypeScript, am trying check if item already exist, but when am defining the previous variable am getting an error: Argument of type '(prev: CartItemsType[]) => CartItemsType[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<CartItemsType[]>', what am i doing wrong here

Here’s my code

```
export type CartItemsType ={
  title: string
  id: number
  description: string
  images: string
  price: number
  amount: number
}

const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState<CartItemsType[]>([] as CartItemsType[])

const handleAddToCart = (clickedItem:CartItemsType) => {
    setCartItems(prev => {
      //check if item is already in cart
      const isItemInCart = prev.find(item =>  item.id === clickedItem.id)
      if(isItemInCart){
        return prev.map( item => item.id === clickedItem.id? {...item, amount: item.amount + 1}: item)
      }
      [...prev, {...clickedItem, amount:1}]
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `setCartItems` with a function.

The problem is that your function doesn't always return a `CartItemsType[]` it might return undefined.

```
export type CartItemsType ={
  title: string
  id: number
  description: string
  images: string
  price: number
  amount: number
}

const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState<CartItemsType[]>([] as CartItemsType[])

const handleAddToCart = (clickedItem:CartItemsType) => {
    setCartItems(prev => {
      //check if item is already in cart
      const isItemInCart = prev.find(item =>  item.id === clickedItem.id)
      if(isItemInCart){
        return prev.map( item => item.id === clickedItem.id? {...item, amount: item.amount + 1}: item)
      }
      // your code has no return in this part.
      return [...prev, {...clickedItem, amount:1}]  // <<<<< missing return?
    })
  }
```